# Flutter Firebase Verify Phone Completer got messed up

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to verify phone with Firebase.

The first verification (the first `verifyPhoneNumberFirebase` call was okay (open the captcha, did not verify but press back, still go to `codeSent`, don't know why).

But the second verification (the second `verifyPhoneNumberFirebase`, which happened after the first one about few seconds) got timed out, ran `codeAutoRetrievalTimeout`. But the weird thing is the `completer` got completed, with the result of the previous call (`codeSent`) even though it got re-inited. Here's the code

```dart
Future<DataResponse> verifyPhoneNumberFirebase({String phoneNumb}) async {
    final completer = Completer<DataResponse>(); /// <--- init and re-init
    _auth
        .verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumb,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        completer.complete(successSomething(verificationId));
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        completer.complete(errorHandling('error');
        }
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
        completer.complete(successSomething(verificationId)); 
         /// the first complete, 
         /// and somehow the second complete, 
         /// even though it did not go to this line in the second call
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        completer.complete(errorHandling('error'); /// <----- already completed ???
      },
    );
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Here the log

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed
_AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:45:31)
...
```

Right now I have no idea how to get the `codeAutoRetrievalTimeout` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing up because you're using the Completer in the `verificationCompleted` callback after it has been used in the `codeSent` callback.

You can remove the `completer.complete` from the `codeSent` block since it is not completing the operation at that point.

Here's an update to your `_auth.verifyPhoneNumber` code:

```dart
     _auth
            .verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumb,
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            completer.complete(successSomething(verificationId));
          },
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            completer.complete(errorHandling('error');
            }
          },
          codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
            successSomething(verificationId); // Remove completer.complete
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
            completer.complete(errorHandling('error'); 
          },
        );
```

Comment: ah yeah I just realize the first call is also call ```codeAutoRetrievalTimeout```. So it leads to the second question: Why the second call did not call any callback ? Maybe because of flutterfire ?

Comment: I don't get the second question completely. One thing to note is that you should use the completer when completing the operation.

Comment: ah yeah here's the thing. After I called this function, I called it again (before it can go into ```codeAutoRetrievalTimeout```). And nothing happened after that. It goes beyond the original question, but that's what I'm truly want to ask here.

Comment: Could you create a new question describing this in detail, especially the part where you call the function twice and drop the link here so I check it out?

Comment: I think I'm gonna leave it to the flutterfire team. I found a way to avoid it (not sure if it works properly).